# Unable to create a many to many field for a new form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

models.py-

```
class B(models.Model):
  filename = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
class A(models.Model):
  file = models.ManyToManyField(B, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(label='Select a file to upload', widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py-

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        a = A()
        form = AForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save(commit=False)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            for f in files:
                fmodel = B(filename=f, user=request.user)
                fmodel.save()
                a.file.add(fmodel)
            a.save()
```

This is generating a 505 Error with the server logs showing it as a OSError with the error being at `fmodel.save()`. I think A expects model B to be already there- not sure how to implement it though. Super new to this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save instance of `A` **before** you add instances of `B`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    a = A()
    form = AForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=a)
    if form.is_valid():
        a = form.save(commit=False)
        a.save()
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        for f in files:
            fmodel = B(filename=f, user=request.user)
            fmodel.save()
            a.file.add(fmodel)
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, not related to this question but can you please help how can I see what request.POST contains? Printing it in python is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see other way than printing `request.POST` to the console.

Comment: Hi Ivan, can you please explaing why do I need both form.save(commit=False) and contract.save(). Trying to get my head around it but no success

Comment: `form.save(commit=False)` returns the instance that you need below to add files to `ManyToManyField` and you cannot do that without saving the instance.